# Compute the binary tree nodes count

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, binary-tree, huffman-code

Is it possible to compute how many nodes have arbitrary binary tree? The leaf count and the depth of every leaf are known (it is Huffman tree actually).

I need it in order to be able to allocate needed memory for the tree before building it actually and to avoid memory re-allocations later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Huffman tree is a [full binary tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Types_of_binary_trees), i.e. every node in the tree has either 0 or 2 children. In this case you need exactly k - 1 inner nodes for k leafs. So the total number of nodes is 2k - 1.